# Full witdh DIV with CustomizR theme

Tags: html, css, wordpress

I'm currently using Customizr theme, with the default settings for the pages set to "full width / no sidebars".

However, when I try do do something like this within a page :

```
<div id="blue-background">
<h1 style="text-align: center;">Full width text with background color ? >/h1>
</div>
```

with the corresponding CSS code :

```
#blue-background{
  width: 100%;
  float: left;
  padding: 20px;
  background: #2680BE;
  position: relative;
}
```

I still have white margins around my text. Increasing the width doesn't seem to be a good solution, so how can I do ?

here is an example of what I get with this code:
http://www.cirnu.com/bandeau/

Answer (score 1):

Your main-wrapper should look like this

```
<div id="main-wrapper">
    <div class="tc-hot-crumble container" role="navigation"><div class="row"><div class="span12"><div class="breadcrumb-trail breadcrumbs" itemprop="breadcrumb"><span class="trail-begin"><a href="http://www.cirnu.com" title="Cirnu" rel="home" class="trail-begin">Accueil</a></span> <span class="sep">»</span> <span class="trail-end">Bandeau</span></div></div></div></div>
    <div role="main">
        <div class="row column-content-wrapper">
            <div id="content" class="span12 article-container">
                <article id="page-623" class="post-623 page type-page status-publish hentry row-fluid">
                    <header class="entry-header">
                        <h1 class="entry-title format-icon">Bandeau</h1>
                        <hr class="featurette-divider __before_content">
                    </header>
                    <div class="entry-content">
                        <div role="main">
                            <div id="blue-background">
                                <div class="container">
                                    <h1 style="text-align: center;">Full width text with background color ?</h1>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </article>
            </div><!--.article-container -->
        </div><!--.row -->
    </div><!-- .container role: main -->
</div>
```

Then you'll need to change some CSS rules:

```
#blue-background {
    padding:20px 0;
    /* then all the other rules you already have */
}

.article-container {

    width:100%;
}
```

Comment: thanks for your reply. I'm not sure to understand where I have to edit the lines of the code. Shall I do it in my page editor in text mode ? PS : I use a child theme !

Comment: Yes, compare the snippet of code above with the original, and you'll see the lines that were changed.

Comment: In my page editor, if I add your code, then mine, the result is also wrapped in the container div. And my breadcrumb text is duplicated. But the text/div is not in full width

Comment: Thanks a lot ! It seems to be a bit larger. But as far as I'm concerned the problems comes from the page editor : it is here where I typed your code, but then the main engine of the theme wraps it before it displays it. Don't you think so ?

Comment: Obviously I misunderstood something, because I paste your code in my page editor (backend) on Wordpress, and when I display the result the breadcrumb text is duplicated

Comment: I used a solution I've just found :
https://wordpress.org/support/topic/create-customizr-full-width-template?replies=13
I have now a full-width display but the text is a bit left-aligned...